# Buckets/Services/Search.ashx 500 error

Tags: content-search, buckets, sitecore-search

We have a `Sitecore 10.3` version and we see the 500 error with the following URL in the console.

Multilist with search is not working along with the Sitecore tab search.

`/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/Services/Search.ashx`

We have looked into all the configs and can't find anything wrong. All the permissions are set correctly too.

Any help to resolve this 500 would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Imran

[image]
[image]

```
Error

Message: Cannot find a query translator with name 'cs.ui.default'.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.ResolveTranslator(String translatorName, IReadOnlyCollection`1 executionContext)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.TranslateQuery(String translatorName, String fieldName, String query, Type propertyType, IReadOnlyCollection`1 executionContext)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.VisitSearch(SearchNode searchNode, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.VisitNot(NotNode node, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.VisitWhere(WhereNode node, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.VisitWhere(WhereNode node, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.VisitWhere(WhereNode node, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.VisitWhere(WhereNode node, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.MapQuery(IndexQuery query)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Linq.Parsing.DefaultQueryTranslator`1.GetQuery(Expression expression)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Linq.Parsing.DefaultQueryExecutor`1.Execute[TElement,TResult](Expression expression)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions.GetResults[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at ItemBuckets.Services.Search.PerformSearch(HttpContext context)
   at ItemBuckets.Services.Search.DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ItemBuckets.Services.Search.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

1725164 09:36:08 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Cannot find a query translator with name 'cs.ui.default'.
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.ResolveTranslator(String translatorName, IReadOnlyCollection`1 executionContext)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.TranslateQuery(String translatorName, String fieldName, String query, Type propertyType, IReadOnlyCollection`1 executionContext)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.VisitSearch(SearchNode searchNode, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.VisitAnd(AndNode node, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.VisitAnd(AndNode node, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.VisitAnd(AndNode node, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.VisitWhere(WhereNode node, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.VisitWhere(WhereNode node, SolrQueryMapperState state)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrQueryMapper.MapQuery(IndexQuery query)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Linq.Parsing.DefaultQueryTranslator`1.GetQuery(Expression expression)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Linq.Parsing.DefaultQueryExecutor`1.Execute[TElement,TResult](Expression expression)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions.GetResults[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at ItemBuckets.Services.Search.PerformSearch(HttpContext context)
   at ItemBuckets.Services.Search.DoProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ItemBuckets.Services.Search.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Check logs files and share stack trace if any error is logged there.

Comment: @SumitHelaiya I have added the error in the post...there isn't much help regarding this either...I don't see any probs with Solr...It is the multilist with search not working. Normal search via solr works fine. Any help is greatly appreciated.